# How can I optimize my controllers so they load faster?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, optimization

Most of the iOS apps I use are very responsive, when I tap on an element it goes to the next view right away. In my app, some of my view controllers take 0.5-1.0 second to load.

My code is all in the `viewDidLoad` method and I'm pretty sure that's the problem but I can't move anything out since I need every single element that I instantiate.

A solution I thought is to move all the work I do in viewDidLoad in a thread then call the main thread when I'm ready to call `addSubview`, would that work even if UIKit is not thread safe? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: What specifically are you doing in viewDidLoad? Are you reading from disk? Are you running network operations? You could offload any of this to a separate thread using grand central dispatch or an operation queue.

Comment: @Philip is right, it all depends on what you are doing in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I'm not doing any network or disk operation (apart from loading images). I'm loading UI elements, UILabel, UITableView, UIImageView, etc.

Comment: If the images are big, you can try loading them on viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Also, are you using methods like drawRect or doing any animations? Those could use up memory.

Comment: Show us what you are doing in viewDidLoad (actual code) and we will be able to help you. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @qegal I'm not doing any drawRect operations.

Comment: @chirag I think you are on to something, the images might be the problem. I'll do some tests. Not sure why I didn't think of that.. sigh.

Comment: What are the best practices in general?

Comment: What about any other drawings perhaps with Core Graphics or animations with Core Animation?

Comment: @qegal No, I load about 4 UITextField, 2 UILabel, 6 UIImageView, 2 plist, 2 UIGestureRecoginzer then add them as subview. The more I think of it, the images or the plist I load are the issue.

Comment: What type of data do the plists hold? You could possibly place that code in the app delegate in `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Answer (score 1):

Try to move some code you might have in viewDidLoad to viewdidAppear. viewDidAppear is being called once the view is presented. If you have to make some hard work, do it there and maybe show aa spinner somewhere while you do that.

Answer (score 1):

What are you exactly doing in viewDidLoad? Btw remember that a view is only loaded when you need it, if you want to switch between views faster I can suggest you to create an initializion phase where you call -view on all the view controller you want to show, maybe helped with a spinner or a progress bar. but pay attention this would work only with intensive loading task and not memory consuming tasks. 
 It sounds very strange your request, so is better the you try to explain better why your viewDidLoad is so slow, maybe there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Define your UI elements in Xcode as part of designing the interface.  That way, Xcode can compile your storeyboard or xib files into the rapidly loading binary form.

Comment: I'm not using IB unfortunately. Thanks though!